# How to Convert 3d to VR view

Tags: 3d, augmented-reality, virtual-reality

I have seen a lot of apps and tools appeared lately that play virtual reality for any google glasses (google cardboard, vr one, etc)

I guess it is only a mathematical conversiom that splits screen and creates 2 cameras for 3d world, each one with lookAt matrix with different vreference point but, which one is the formula? Or which is the way to convert 3d models to vr scene?

Comment: There are many articles about this. Try http://paulbourke.net/exhibition/vpac/opengl.html or http://www.orthostereo.com/geometryopengl.html.

Comment: thank you @AlexCohn I'll take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find documentation on internet but I recommend you using unity with cardboard sdk